# How to efficiently spark read source data with custom schema with complex fields?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, distributed-computing, apache-spark-dataset

Let us say that I have the following raw source data delimited by comma `,` but there are some `X` number of fields that have a very custom format. For simplicity, I have minimized this example to 3 fields/columns. In this case, the custom field is the `address` with special formatting (key/values surrounded by braces). There may be other fields with a completely different format.

```
Bob,35,[street:75917;city:new york city;state:ny;zip:10000]
...
Roger,75,[street:81659;city:los angeles;state:ca;zip:99999]
```

Case classes:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int, address: Address)
case class Address(street: String, city: String, state: String, zip: Int)
```

What is the most efficient way to process the source data (including parsing of the address field) into `Dataset[Person]`?

Currently, there are two options that come to mind:

***Option 1*** - Perform row by row manual conversion:

```
val df = df.read.csv(source)
val dataset = df.map(row => 
    Person(row.getString("_c0"), row.getInt("_c1"), getAddress(row.getString("_c3")))
).as[Person]
```

***Option 2*** - Utilize `UDF` (user defined functions) for the custom formatted columns and use `withColumn` and `withColumnRenamed`:

```
val udfAddress : UserDefinedFunction = udf((address: String) => toAddressObject(address))
var df = df.read.csv(source)
df = df.withColumnRenamed("_c0", "name").withColumn("name", col("name").cast(StringType))
       .withColumnRenamed("_c1", "age").withColumn("age", col("age").cast(IntegerType))
       .withColumnRenamed("_c2",  "address").withColumn("address", udfAddress(col("address")))
val dataset = df.as[Person]
```

Generally, between **Option 1** and **Option 2**, what is more efficient and why? Also, if there is another option that is more efficient in processing/parsing custom formatted fields, I am open to other options as well. Is there a better option that involves composing a StructType with StructFields manually? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of the alternative might be-

> Please note that, I haven't conducted any performance testing

### Load the test data

```scala
 val data =
      """
        |Bob,35,[street:75917;city:new york city;state:ny;zip:10000]
        |Roger,75,[street:81659;city:los angeles;state:ca;zip:99999]
      """.stripMargin

    val stringDS = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\,").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString("|"))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df = spark.read
      .option("sep", "|")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
//      .option("header", "true")
      //      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS)
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +-----+---+----------------------------------------------------+
      * |_c0  |_c1|_c2                                                 |
      * +-----+---+----------------------------------------------------+
      * |Bob  |35 |[street:75917;city:new york city;state:ny;zip:10000]|
      * |Roger|75 |[street:81659;city:los angeles;state:ca;zip:99999]  |
      * +-----+---+----------------------------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- _c1: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- _c2: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

### Convert Dataframe of Row to Person

```scala
val person = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[Person].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
    val toAddr = udf((map: Map[String, String]) => Address(map("street"), map("city"), map("state"), map("zip").toInt))
    val p = df.withColumn("_c2", translate($"_c2", "[]",""))
      .withColumn("_c2", expr("str_to_map(_c2, ';', ':')"))
      .withColumn("_c2", toAddr($"_c2"))
      .toDF(person.map(_.name): _*)
      .as[Person]


    p.show(false)
    p.printSchema()

    /**
      * +-----+---+---------------------------------+
      * |name |age|address                          |
      * +-----+---+---------------------------------+
      * |Bob  |35 |[75917, new york city, ny, 10000]|
      * |Roger|75 |[81659, los angeles, ca, 99999]  |
      * +-----+---+---------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- name: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- street: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- zip: integer (nullable = false)
      */
```